# how can I solve this error code in angular bootstrap ng serve?

Tags: angular, firebase, bootstrap-4, angular7, angular-components

1- in "app.compomnet.html " I use a starter template code 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/starter-template/

2- I installed bootsrap4 "npm I bootstap@4 --save " in terminal

3-  I add this references into style.css

4- in style.css **'@import'~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'**

5- I tried to type '**ng s --o** 'this error occurred .

[![error message in terminal ][1]][1]
[image: 2nd error message]

I tried to check if the code in style.css is correct or not 
"@import'~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
can anyone elaborate error

[1]: error message in lines

ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:125:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:39:54)
    at Promise (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\styles.js:47:35)
    at new Promise ()
    at Object.load (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\styles.js:46:28)
    at loadImportContent (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules\postcss-import\index.js:236:34)
    at Promise.all.resolved.map.file (D:\shopping-cart\node_modules\postcss-import\index.js:210:18)[0m

Comment: Please copy and paste the error text rather than providing screenshots. Search engines don't crawl text in images, so people are unlikely to find your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to your style.css

**@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";**

Answer (score -1):

you need to add bootsrap to angular.json

```
// scroll down to the style section and add bootstrap line below
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
```

Comment: Yes ..it is the solution ..but why this is the correct ..or when i scrolled down and put this below ..this is the solution.can you elaborate please ?